# SQL Server 2008 list items not in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

A simple query that should be looking into `systemSoftware` table and software table and displaying only the `softwareId` that are not inside the `systemSoftware` table.

Here is my query so far...

```
SELECT s.softwareId AS 'Software ID',
    s.softwareDescription AS 'Software Description',
    sv.vendorName AS 'Vendor Name',
    c.cityName AS 'City Name'
FROM software AS s
JOIN systemSoftware AS ss
ON s.softwareId = ss.softwareId
JOIN softwareVendor AS sv
ON s.vendorId = sv.vendorId
JOIN city AS c
ON sv.zipCode = c.zipCode
WHERE s.softwareId NOT IN (ss.softwareId)
ORDER BY s.softwareId
GO
```

When I remove the NOT it displays all the `softwareId` rows that are in `systemSoftware`.

Problem is I want the opposite. The ones that are not in `systemSoftware`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a left outer join:

```
SELECT ss.softwareId AS 'Software ID',
    s.softwareDescription AS 'Software Description',
    sv.vendorName AS 'Vendor Name',
    c.cityName AS 'City Name'
FROM software AS s
left outer JOIN systemSoftware AS ss
ON s.softwareId = ss.softwareId
left outer JOIN softwareVendor AS sv
ON s.vendorId = sv.vendorId
left outer JOIN city AS c
ON sv.zipCode = c.zipCode
WHERE ss.softwareId is NULL
ORDER BY s.softwareId
```

I also changed the `ORDER BY`, since it doesn't make sense to order by a column that is not present.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Left Outer Joins, I need to examine this further. Works great!

Comment: @DDDD: see Jeff Atwood's [A Visual Explanation of JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) for starters